# Accessing SQLite data through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

For example, if I have this code:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('user.new_domain') }}" class="form" role="form" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    <p>{{ form.name(placeholder="name", onkeyup="timing()") }}
      <span class="error">
      {% if form.name.errors %}
        {% for error in form.name.errors %}
          {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    </span>
    </p>
</form>
```

`timing()` is a function within a javascript file that I have inside a `<script>` tag in my code. I want `timing()` to be able to access my sqlite database info and check to see if whatever the user entered into the form exists in my database. Is this even the right way to do this? Through javascript? how else am I supposed to run javascript functions that are dependent on sqlite data? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to send a call to another [route](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.route) in your app that returns a string (plain or JSON, whichever is more useful). The Ajax call then uses it's `success` function to parse that data and act on it as appropriate.

So, in addition to your code that is only rendered by Flask:

```
{% if form.name.errors %}
    {% for error in form.name.errors %}
        {{ error }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

you'd need to act via JavaScript:

```
<script>
    function timing() {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "some url",
            data: {
                key: "value"
            },
            success: function(data) {
                // do something
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

and the code in your app would be something like (based on the fact that your results are coming from another Python file that actually does the querying):

```
from that_other_file import the_querying_function

@app.route('/some_url', methods=['POST'])
def some_url():
    return the_querying_function(request.POST['key'])
```

This uses [HttpResponse.POST](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST). Replace `key` (in the JS and Python) with whatever you're trying to get from the form.

Comment: How would I get the route in my app to hold the data I want? For example, in Flask, when you  `return (database data)` at the end of a function under a `@app.route (/test/)`, how do I actually get the database data to be returned? The data will come from a python file that queries the database, so how do I return that?

Comment: I added a bit more to the answer. Does that help, @James?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was asking. I will look into all of this, thank you very much!

Comment: I'm back with a question. I have it all working, but what is stopping someone from just navigating to `@app.route('/some_url')` without making an ajax call? Just like in their browser by typing example.com/some_url. Or is making a new view with a new URL not the proper way to do this...

Comment: Wouldn't this throw a method error and display that on the page? Should I just redirect  `if method == 'GET'`, instead of displaying error? I guess I just want to know the textbook, proper way to do this, and i'm having trouble googling it.

Comment: Sure, you could do that. It's `if request.method == 'GET': return redirect(url_for('your_next_method'))`

Comment: Right, that makes sense. The docs are pretty rich for all that syntax, so i'm in luck. Thanks @Celeo!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes it is possible but on limited browsers, see the link for details. http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/

Long answer is it might be smart to use your backend to access these (perhaps through an API?) Here's one such example for Flask (although I am not sure what you are using https://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: You might also want to consider the following library: https://github.com/kripken/sql.js

Comment: I am using Flask. While I will look into those links, is this the proper way to do this? What is the best/proper way to do this? Surely people do this all the time? (comparing user input via a form, to data in their database that is)